# How to change default notification table name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I want to change `notification` table name, so I changed the migration file:

```
php artisan notification:table

Schema::create('member_notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->uuid('id')->primary();
      $table->string('type');
      $table->morphs('notifiable');
      $table->text('data');
      $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

And trying to use `$table` in `Notification` class :

```
protected $table = 'member_notifications';
```

But when I trying to store notification in database I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "notifications" does not exist
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change default *notifications* table to your custom table, you should do 3 things:

1. Change table name in migration file to `member_notifications`. Run migration.
2. Create your model, for example `DatabaseMemberNotification`. Extend it from `Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification` and override property

   ```
   protected $table = 'member_notifications';
   ```
3. In default `User` model add this function:

   ```
   public function notifications()
   {
       return $this->morphMany(DatabaseMemberNotification::class, 'notifiable')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
   }
   ```

   Actually it will override `notifications()` method in  `HasDatabaseNotifications` trait.

   **Note**: first parameter should be your new model class.

Answer (score -7):

go to vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/DatabaseNotification.php

and change protected $table to the desired table name

in your case

```
protected $table = 'member_notifications';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an stable solution, because after update I should edit this file again